# Scroll to anchor with specific href

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery, if the cookie `url` is set, the `scroll_to_href` function is called and the `URL` variable is passed in to it.

My problem is with the `scroll_to_href` funcion, I'm attempting to scroll to an anchor where the href equals the value of my `url` var (it's re-declared as `href` in the `scroll_to_href` function). Currently this does not work, I'm not pulling in errors, could anyone suggest what the issue might be?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if($.cookie('url')){
    var url = $.cookie('url');
    scroll_to_href(url);
 } 


  function scroll_to_href(url){ 
    var href = $("a[href='"+ url +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: href.offset().top},'slow');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle for testing your code: https://jsfiddle.net/dsbnw50r/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Static url
    scroll_to_href('http://google.com');
    function scroll_to_href(url){ 
        var href = $("a[href='"+ url +"']");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: href.offset().top},'slow');
    }
});
```

Either you cookie isn't set or the URL is different.